# VS code: how to specify Aura bundle folder?

Tags: salesforcedx, aura, vs-code

Can anyone explain this error, that I've got in VS Code recently? When I tried to deploy code to my Org, I got this:

*SfdxError: You must specify the Aura bundle folder, not an individual component.*

I Googled it, but didn't find anything, that could help.

.xml

[image: manifest]

Comment: you can only deploy the 'Aura Lightning components' that has all files(component, controller, helper, renderer etc). Did you mention any single file name? That must be the reason of this error. You need to mention only the bundle name, ex :`MyLightningComponent` instead of `MyLightningComponent.cmp`

Comment: OK, so where do I need to mention the bundle name? I didn't change any setting for it.

Comment: I guess you need to check your package.xml.

Comment: I only changed API version in manifest: from 45.0 to 46.0 and that's it. Maybe you can take a look at it and tell me, what sould I change or add to this .xml?

Comment: Yes please share your package.xml, sfdx command and what else you are doing for this deployment.

Comment: Edited the question. I just try to deploy my component and i get the error. I tried different orgs, on which I didn't have such problem before, but even there I have it now.

Comment: What commands did you use for deployment...was it a scratch org or non-scratch org...refer this [article](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-salesforcedx-sfdx-with-non-scratch-orgs/) for details

Comment: It's a non-scratch org and I used "Deploy Source to Org" command

Comment: Yes. its due to the recent upgrade the version. so either select the folder from left side and deploy using right click or downgrade your version. Refer - https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1635 and https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1640

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The underlying issue has been resolved.

As a background information:

This bug was recently introduced to the VSCode toolbox. Here's a bug report related to this: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1635

In order to deploy, right click on the LWC folder in the editor tree and select "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org". Using the deploy on save functionality will fail, since it currently only deploys the single file.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy to org select the master folder and then select deploy source to org don't deploy the single file

[image]

Comment: Previously I made auto-deploy on save in settings, and it worked fine. Yes, it works like you said, but how to resolve my problem, that I can save files, like I used to do before? Without needing to manually select my project folder and deploy it to org?

Answer (score 1):

Done! Turns out, reinstalling Salesforce CLI resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not save individual file but to save the whole component folder
That will works